# Why we can not fulfill our desires?

Tags: desire, wisdom

What characteristics in universe have that doesn't let us to fulfill our desires ?

Why we get more and more desires through fulfilling desires ? (What characteristics of desires have that we have to know to understand better about desires)

Comment: Because sensual desire is a bottomless pit, it's like drinking salt water, the more one drinks, the more one gets thirsty. However, there's one exception, the desire for enlightenment. See this sutta for more details: https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn51/sn51.015.than.html

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question.

The reason why we can't full-fill our desires is because of the impermanent nature in the world. Everything around us is subjected to impermanence. This includes the happiness that we get from worldly things.

For example:
You buy a car(because you desire), now your happy. Then you get bored overtime, and you want a better car.  Because your satisfaction is impermanent. You had the satisfaction when you bought it but then it died away. So you buy a better car (to full-fill your deep desires). Then two cars, then five cars. Someday, you can have all the cars in the world and still not end up satisfied. Because your satisfactions are impermanent. Its born and it dies. Like everything else in this universe.

So the simple answer to  your question "Why we get more and more desires through fulfilling desires ? (What characteristics of desires have that we have to know to understand better about desires)":

 
**Impermanence in this universe** or **Impermanence in satisfaction of desires** to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Everything, except for Nirvana, is subjected to [the three marks of existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_marks_of_existence):

- all compounded phenomena are impermanent (anitya);
- all compounded phenomena are suffering (duḥkha);
- all phenomena, including Nirvana, is without self (anātman);

Whatever which is impermanent is unsatisfactory since whatever experience is unsatisfactory as one has to part with what is pleasant and satisfactory and has to come with what is unsatisfactory.

Not being control also leads to unsatisfactoriness as one is not fully in control and not everything turns out satisfactorily. In a world with finite resources not all wants can be satisfied due to the lack of absolute control over what can be got.